# About monotonicity of parabolic Kazhdan Lusztig polynomials

Tags: rt.representation-theory, polynomials, kazhdan-lusztig

Let $W_I$ be the parabolic subgroup generated by $I$, ${}^IW$ be the set of minimal length right coset representative of $W_I$ in $W$, and $w_I$ be the longest element in $W_I$.

Let $P_{u,v}$ be the Kazhdan Lusztig polynomial of $W$, $P_{u,v}^{I,-1}$ be the Kazhdan Lusztig polynomial of ${}^IW$ of type $-1$ and $P_{u,v}^{I,q}$ be the Kazhdan Lusztig polynomial of ${}^IW$ of type $q$, respectively.

On p.479 of the paper **["Inequalities on Bruhat graphs,R- and Kazhdan–Lusztig polynomials"](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S009731651200163X?token=D7A52D62FD6FF6D75E121E7C01506C519B4D21C0A76D08634BFAF9BAAEBBB2DF136B908346EF8EE6EAF046406D93C5C9)**, it holds that

[image]

where $\ge$ is the $q$-coefficientwise partial order in $\mathbb{Z}[q]$.

It is well-known that $P_{u,v}^{I,-1}(q)=P_{w_Iu,w_Iv}(q)$ for all $u,v\in {}^IW$.
Since $u\le v\iff w_Iu\le w_Iv$ for all $u,v\in {}^IW$, it holds that: 
**If $u\le v\le w$ in ${}^IW$, then $P_{u,w}^{I,-1}\ge P_{v,w}^{I,-1}$.**

> I would like to ask whether the statement:
>   "If $u\le v\le w$ in ${}^IW$, then $P_{u,w}^{I,q}\ge P_{v,w}^{I,q}$" is true or not?